# Problems on Longtables

Tags: spacing, longtable, multicolumn, underline

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{harvard-thesis}

\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}
\newcommand*\0[1]{{\large#1}}
\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}}
    {\end{smallmatrix}\right)}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{stackengine}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter % undo the wrong changes made by mathspec
\let\RequirePackage\original@RequirePackage
\let\usepackage\RequirePackage
\makeatother

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\usepackage{libertine}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\th@plain{\thm@headpunct{:}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{ορισμός}{Ορισμός}[chapter]
\newtheorem{λήμμα}{Λήμμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{θεώρημα}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{κατασκευή}{Κατασκευή}[chapter]
\newtheorem{πόρισμα}{Πόρισμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{αλγόριθμος}{Αλγόριθμος}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{απόδειξη*}{Απόδειξη}

\setromanfont[Numbers=Lining, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}

\renewcommand\listtablename{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{8pt} 
\def\mtctitle{Περιεχόμενα}%
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq,bigstrut}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.8}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\smallerrel}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\smallerrelaux{#1}}}
\newcommand{\smallerrelaux}[2]{\raisebox{.1ex}{\scalebox{.75}{$#1#2$}}}

\newcommand{\smallin}{\smallerrel{\in}}
\newcommand{\smallnotin}{\smallerrel{\notin}}

\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,greek]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand*{\tablename}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Πίνακας}}}%
}

\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Εισαγωγή}
\section{Εισαγωγικές έννοιες}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c}
    \caption{$BA(12, 5, 3, 2), r_{1}  = 4, r_{2} = 1, n _{12}^{22}  = 2$} \\ 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{$n_{1}^{2} = 4, n_{11}^{22} = 2$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$n _{2}^{2}= 6$}\\
    \midrule
    1& 1& 1& 2&1 \\
    2& 2& 2& 3&1 \\
    3& 3& 3& 1&1 \\
    1& 1& 2& 1&2 \\
    1& 3& 3& 3&2 \\
    2& 1& 1& 1&2 \\
    2& 2& 3& 2&2 \\
    3& 2& 2& 2&2 \\
    3& 3& 1& 3&2 \\
    1& 2& 1& 1&3 \\
    2& 3& 2& 2&3 \\
    3& 1& 3& 3&3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

So, I ask:

1) How to make the first 4 columns exactly down and centering of `$n_{1}^{2} = 4, n_{11}^{22} = 2$` ?

2) How to reduce the space between the `caption` and the `toprule`?

3) How to make the `toprule` to underline the whole caption? The same length of the `toprule`, I also want for the `midrule` and the `bottomrule`.

The `harvard-thesis.cls` is avalaible here:[harvard-thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd), but I have done lots of changes!

I write the whole code, because I have changed lots of things and maybe one of them creates my problems!

Comment: And I have many codes too... But no reason to upload all of them here :P (Please say some words about your problem and what you want to achieve). Also please try to reduce the code only to the needed part that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Καλησπέρα!  What is the problem?

Comment: @koleygr lots of people want the whole code, to give an answer. That is why I upload all of it.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis, in your case the whole code real needed because after your questions I see that you want so specific width for the table that depends from almost every line of your code. But we also need your template's code (a link or something)

Comment: @koleygr This is the whole code. Do you want the `harvard-thesis.cls` as I have changed it?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis just the link of where did you found that cls would be enough. But you already have an answer... try changing the `5mm` in the columntype definition of the answer to your needs and specific font needs

Comment: @koleygr I have written the link of the cls.

Comment: VassilisChasiotis, nice... needed there. But doesn't @Zarko's answer fits your needs? You can just play with the distances as I said before...

Comment: @koleygr I tried it. But I have the same results! I do not know why!

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis, Just checked... You are right.. something redefines p column type... Looking for a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67248/discussion-between-vassilis-chasiotis-and-koleygr).

Answer (score 1):

From tests and after our discussion I realized that this template is not appropriate for most column types. I tried with `p` and `m` (I think from `array` package) columntypes and I failed. I removed almost every package and just left the template and could not use the above columntypes.

So, our fix was something like:

```
\documentclass{harvard-thesis}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{Z}{@{\hskip 30pt}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Εισαγωγή}
\section{Εισαγωγικές έννοιες}
\begin{longtable}{c Z c Z c Z  c ZZ c Z}
    \caption{$BA(12, 5, 3, 2), r_{1}  = 4, r_{2} = 1, n _{12}^{22}  = 2$}\vspace{-10pt} \\ 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}cZZ}{$n_{1}^{2} = 4, n_{11}^{22} = 2$}&\multicolumn{1}{cZ}{$n _{2}^{2}= 6$}\\
    \midrule
    1& 1& 1& 2&1 \\
    2& 2& 2& 3&1 \\
    3& 3& 3& 1&1 \\
    1& 1& 2& 1&2 \\
    1& 3& 3& 3&2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

But I personally recommend not to use such templates that gives such errors.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

[image]

i haven't `harvard-thesis` not greek fonts, however above image is independent from them:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow}

\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5mm}}c}
    \caption{$BA(12, 5, 3, 2), r_{1}  = 4, r_{2} = 1, n _{12}^{22}  = 2$} \\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{$n_{1}^{2} = 4,\ n_{11}^{22} = 2$}
    &   $n _{2}^{2}= 6$\\
    \midrule
1   & 1 & 1 & 2 &   1 \\
2   & 2 & 2 & 3 &   1 \\
3   & 3 & 3 & 1 &   1 \\
1   & 1 & 2 & 1 &   2 \\
1   & 3 & 3 & 3 &   2 \\
2   & 1 & 1 & 1 &   2 \\
2   & 2 & 3 & 2 &   2 \\
3   & 2 & 2 & 2 &   2 \\
3   & 3 & 1 & 3 &   2 \\
1   & 2 & 1 & 1 &   3 \\
2   & 3 & 2 & 2 &   3 \\
3   & 1 & 3 & 3 &   3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

note: `hyperref` package with rare exception had to be loaded last in the preamble.

Comment: It look very nice, but in my output the columns have a big big distance between them

Comment: than you change something. width of the first four columns is 5mm!

Comment: I know, but I have lots of space! I changed the 5mm, but I have the same!

Comment: sorry, my crystal ball is busy somewhere else, so i cant see, what you doing. i'm convinced, that if you in my example change only `\documentclass{book}` to `\documentclass{harvard-thesis}` you will obtain the very same result as i show in answer.